# Matrices question - problem with task or with my understanding?

Tags: matrices

I tried to solve this question but it turned out that my logic was wrong. Can someone please explain to me why my logic is incorrect and why these answers are correct?

1. Prove or disprove by an example: If the $2$-row matrix $A$ is such that $AB = B$ for each order $2$ matrix $B$, then $A$ is the unit matrix (i.e. the matrix with $1$s on the diagonal and zeros everywhere else).

I tried to disprove it by saying that if $B$ is the zero matrix, then in that case $AB = 0 = B$ and $A$ is not the unit matrix.
But it turns out my try was wrong and the right answer was this 
: **[solution to the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POIAh.png)**

Answer (score 2):

your hypothesis is that the equation $AB=B$ holds for any matrix not only for the null matrix. Try to use different matrix such as for $B$ take the identity matrix or any invertible one